# Add layout elements to Layout with a View

Tags: android

I'm trying out the Finger Paint api demo and I'm trying to add buttons to it. I have included

```
<view class="com.triopsys.imosandroid.ViewControllers.SignatureViewController$MyView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

In my layout xml, but I can't add buttons on the top or bottom of this view.

Comment: may be thats because, its width and height is taking the entire screen...

Comment: It's the width and height of the parent's group, so LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add buttons to a view... You need a view group ... Linear Layout/Relative Layout.... Rather than trying to do the markup yourself use the visual editor and add two buttons and then take a look at the xml it should point you in the right direction

Comment: The visual editor won't let me do anything, and XML doesn't change anything either. The view is contained in a linear layout and I'm trying to place a couple buttons above or below the the linear layout in another linear layout.